# preparing UI in 2nd screen blocks 1st screen ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, nsthread

There are two screens in my app in the 1st screen i have `CollectionView` when a cell is selected it is redirected to 2nd screen. In the 2nd screen `ViewDidLoad` method i'm adding programatically `ScrollView` with 30 `ScrollView` in it and each `Scrollview` has buttons and images.Until this operation is completed it is blocking 1st screen after completion of operation 2nd screen is loaded.
     Until the operations in `ViewDidLoad` method in 2nd screen which is used for preparing UI
is completed 2nd screen is not loaded.

Comment: are these images loaded from a server call? simply adding the UI elements will not consume much time.

Comment: i stopped loading images and i checked without images but the same problem persist.I'm using storyboard for seguing from screen1 to 2

Comment: is there any other loading from server?? any content or something?

Comment: No content from server.content is read from array.I'm adding ScrollView with 30 ScrollViews in it.Every ScrollView has image and text,will it block the UI,can I do it asynchronously so that i can show activityIndicator by the it is prepared.

Answer (score 0):

you are writing your code in `viewDidLoad` ...

So viewDidLoad method calls only one time when you click on First Screen and navigate to second Screen...

So Please Use `viewWillAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad` because `viewWillAppear` calls each and every time when you navigate to secondscreen...

Try Your all code in `viewWillAppear` and you can get your solution....